# parse MS Graph SecureScores JSON in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to parse JSON data which I have stored in a SQL table. The json is pulled from MS graph API. This is the example data sample:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/securescore-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

This is what I have so far, but it returns 0 rows. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT x.*
FROM Odata_json AS c
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(jsonValue, '$.controlScores')) 
WITH (
controlName nvarchar(100) '$.controlName', 
description nvarchar(1000) '$.description'
)
AS x 
where oID = 11
```

I can get the first section to return results using:

```
SELECT  JSON_VALUE(a.Value, '$.activeUserCount') AS activeUserCount, JSON_VALUE(a.Value, '$.createdDateTime') AS  createdDateTime, JSON_VALUE(a.Value, '$.currentScore') AS  currentScore, JSON_VALUE(a.Value, '$.enabledServices') AS  enabledServices, JSON_VALUE(a.Value, '$.licensedUserCount') AS licensedUserCount, JSON_VALUE(a.Value, '$.maxScore') AS maxScore, JSON_VALUE(a.Value, '$.id') AS id, JSON_VALUE(a.Value, '$.azureTenantId') AS  azureTenantId, JSON_VALUE(a.Value, '$.deviceScore') AS deviceScore, JSON_VALUE(a.Value, '$.dataScore') AS dataScore, JSON_VALUE(a.Value, '$.identityScore') AS identityScore, y.*
                     FROM  Odata_json AS c
                        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(jsonValue, '$')) AS a 
                        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(a.[value],'$.controlScores')
                        WITH (
                        controlName nvarchar(100) '$.controlName', 
    description nvarchar(1000) '$.description'
                        ) AS y 
                         where oID = 11
```

But is it possible to return the controlScores array either in one query or maybe separate

Comment: Well, there's no `deletedDateTime` value in the JSON at the presented link. Perhaps the `Odata_json.jsonValue` isn't storing the JSON you think it is? Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74531030/edit) your question to include the actual JSON that you're attempting to query - as text, not screen shot(s).

Comment: `where oID = 11` or `where oID = 12` maybe try the first query with oid=12?

Comment: I copied the wrong sql into my post. I've edited it now